# How to add non time-series data into a time series dataset for ML?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, neural-network, time-series, reinforcement-learning

I would like to train a reinforcement learning model on multiple different time series datasets.

Each dataset is independent of one another and have additional attributes, such as location, weather, temperature, hardware etc.

I was wondering whether somebody could tell me the best way to add this information to my dataset. Do I just make a feature for each attribute and duplicate the data for each tick in the time series or is there a more effective efficient way of doing this?

I believe I will have to train/fit the model in batches, whereby each batch is a new/different dataset, but happy to be corrected on that.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What code do you have so far? If each dataset is contained in its own dataframe, it sounds like you want to merge dataframes to get a training set.

Comment: @DSteman My code creates individual pandas dataframes for each independent time series. It then appends them together to create a training set (which is fed to the model in 15min batches). My question relates to how I add non time series data to this. Is it as simple as creating additional columns?